# Comparing a model with a latent variable to one without

Tags: model-selection, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I would like to test whether my 3 dependent variables all load onto an underlying latent variable or if a latent variable is not necessary to explain the relationship between the IVs and the DVs. In other words, I want to compare the two models below:
[image: model 1]

[image: model 2]

Both models provide good fits to the data according to typical fit statistics (chi-square, SRMR, CFI) and when I compare the models using a chi-square difference test, it is not significant. What can I say about which model better describes the underlying structure of the data? Is the second model more parsimonious because it doesn't require a latent variable? I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Update: I turns out that it is not appropriate to do a chi-square difference test on these two models because they are not nested.